# Disable HTTP/2 on Nexus Repository Manager OSS 3

Tags: nexus, nexus3

I'm new to **Repository Manager OSS** and i need to disable `HTTP/2` for my SSL-Certificate. But i don't know where i can turn off `HTTP/2`. Can anyone say it to me?

Answer (score 0):

I found it there: `$NEXUS_PATH/etc/jetty/jetty-https.xml`